# No retain in instance variables

Tags: objective-c

In Effective Objective-C 2.0 there's the following snipped of code:

```
@interface EOCClass : NSObject {
    id _object;
}
@end

@implementation EOCClass
- (void)setup{
    _object = [EOCOtherClass new];
}
@end
```

The author then states that:

> "The _object instance variable does not automatically retain its value under manual reference counting but does under ARC."

I tested the above snippet in XCode and the instance variable does retain the value (i.e. everything seems to work fine).

What does the author mean by the sentence above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He means that:

> The _object instance variable does not automatically retain its value under manual reference counting but does under ARC.

Simple as that. If this works under MRC, it works for one reason:

```
[SomeClass new]
```

is equivalent to

```
[[SomeClass alloc] init]
```

so`_object` will have a reference count of one no matter what.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but it doesn't clarify why the author would say that _object doesn't automatically retain its value under MRC, since [SomeClass new] would make the object have a retain count of 1, and therefore would be retained under MRC.

Comment: @user2599140 No, it wouldn't be retained. It would be allocated with a reference count of one. MRC doesn't use strong pointers, ARC does, and under ARC, it would be automatically retained **in addition** to being allocated (since ivars are strong by default).

Comment: @user2599140 Hopefully H2CO3 has helped explain it a bit more for you. I agree it's awkwardly worded in the book, making it a little confusing. I'll definitely fix that for the future. Feel free to continue chat on our email chain if you want. Definitely a good idea to make sure you understand this stuff!

Answer (score 3):

The book author is confusing two different things. First, the expression:

```
[EOCOtherClass new]
```

Returns a reference to an object for which the caller has ownership (as one of possibly many owners). Under MRC at some point the caller must arrange to relinquish that ownership (`release` or `autorelease`). The caller can do that either directly or indirectly by passing on the ownership. Under ARC the ownership is managed automatically.

Secondly, the declaration:

```
id _object;
```

Declares a variable which hold a reference of type `id`. Under MRC that is all it does, variables to *do not* own whatever their containing reference references - they are simply a place to store references and ownership management is separate.

However under ARC variables *can* own what they reference, and the default ownership mode of an instance variable is `strong` - meaning the variable maintains ownership of what it references. When a new reference is stored into a variable then ownership is relinquished over previously referenced object and ownership asserted over the newly referenced object. All this is automatic and handled by ARC.

Under both MRC and ARC the code fragment shown allocates and owns an instance of `EOCOtherClass`. Under MRC that ownership must be manually relinquished at some point. Under ARC that ownership will be relinquished automatically at the appropriate time.

Comment: So, under MRC the runtime doesn't have a notion of object ownership? This does make sense, since the retain instance method merely returns self. Retain/release seem to merely increase/decrease retain count, without caring about object ownership.

Is this why the author says that _object doesn't retain its value? Is he implying that under MRC _object doesn't own the object?

Comment: Not exactly. Both MRC and ARC work on the notion of object ownership; and under MRC *variables* (var) don't have a notion of owning objects.  *Objects* are owned, you refer to objects via *references* (ref), and you store refs in *vars*.  With MRC the programmer manages ownership; storing a ref in a var does not effect ownership.  With ARC ownership is managed automatically and is determined by what is done with the refs. If a ref is stored in a var declared (usually implicitly) to hold `strong` refs then that action determines that ownership is required - so effectively vars become owners.